# What does the myid file do in zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am learning zookeeper. I see that the config file relies on a separate config file called "myid." 
I know that all installations have the same config file so I guess the myid file lets a particular zookeeper instance know its ID within the system.  Why does an installation need to know its own ID? Is there a particular reason, from an architectural standpoint, why this information is split into its own config file?

Answer (score 3):

The id gives zookeeper a stable identifier, and this [link](http://markmail.org/message/cvzz3tq3gievicqe) might be helpful.